# Unable to forward port on "tp link archer c6"

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, port-forwarding, tp-link

m using my own local Ubuntu server 18.04, and trying to host that world wide.  i am also using Tp link Archer c6 rourter for port forwarding. I can forward port 21, but unable to forward any of others.

[image]

[image]

I am unable to find any of solutions on web.Please solve it as fast as you can.

Comment: You need a static IP from your ISP. You need another setting that you may have already done. Assign static internal IP in DHCP settings.